# Primefaces BarChart XAXIS Tick Labels Changed After Rotation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, rotation, jqplot, bar-chart

I am using primefaces 3.5RC1 and want to rotate tick labels of bar chart.I wrote the code below,and rotated tick labels.However,tick labels turned into numbers.Tick labels should have been strings like 'No Family' or any other fanily name.How can i fix this?

```
function barChartExtender(){
      this.cfg.axes= {
                   xaxis: {
                             tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                             tickOptions: {
                                       angle: 60
                                  }
                          }
                   };
}
```

The labels after rotation
[image: Labels with number]

The labels before rotation
[image: Labels meant to be]

Please help...
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set   `tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer` or any extender for rotation.

For PrimeFaces versions earlier than 5.0, use **xaxisAngle** attribute on your component like;

`xaxisAngle="-50"` like:

```
<p:barChart id="basic" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" xaxisAngle="60" 
      title="Basic Bar Chart" min="0" max="200" style="height:300px"/>
```

For newer versions see:

- [Primefaces 5 Rotated Axis Tick Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835755/primefaces-5-rotated-axis-tick-labels)