# Primefaces 5 Rotated Axis Tick Labels

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, bar-chart

In Primefaces 4 we can configure the rotation of axis tick labels as below:

```
<p:barChart id="idBars" value="#{chartBean.modelChart}" 
                            [...]
                            style="xaxisAngle=-30"
                            >
</p:barChart>
```

Now, how can I configure the rotation of axis tick labels using Primefaces 5 or higher?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make this in the model. (http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/model/chart/BarChartModel.html)

```
 Axis xAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
 xAxis.setTickAngle(-30);
```